# Why is the decision making for a hypothesis test opposite when testing for a slope and a mean?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, linear-regression

[image]

When conducting a hypothesis test for a sample mean, we reject the null hypothesis when the test statistic is *less than* the critical value, or the P-value is less than the rejection region. Why is that when testing for a slope, (as stated above)we fail to reject the null hypothesis when the test statistic is less than the critical value?

Comment: I am not sure "When conducting a hypothesis test for a sample mean, we reject the null hypothesis when the test statistic is *less than* the critical value" is correct in general or even usually

Answer (score 1):

We do not do as you say in the case of the sample mean. In that case, the test statistic is $t=\frac{\bar x-\bar x_0}{s_e}$, and $t$ is large in absolute value when the sample mean $\bar x$ is far from the null value $\bar x_0$. The situation is exactly analogous with the case of linear regression.

You didn't cite the text you've quoted, but it is contains a blatant error about one of the most fundamental aspects of hypothesis testing. We can never "conclude $H_0$", because the null hypothesis is that a parameter has some specific value, something that is impossible to conclude for a continuous quantity. I suggest you stop using this reference. The correct conclusion is that we *do not reject* the null hypothesis, which is entirely different than accepting it. In effect, we do nothing.